# How to send prop value using function in react js/react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component

In My application i am using one ErrorMessage component which is responsible display the error message in Text with different messages with different colors.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class ErrorMessage extends Component {
constructor(props) { 
super(props);

this.state = {
};
}

render() {
  //console.log("props:",this.props);
  //debugger;
return (
  <View style={styles.form}>
    <Text style={{color:this.props.color}}> {this.props.ErrorMessage} </Text>
  </View>
);
}

}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
form: {
},
});
```

I tried to use my component with below possible cases

```
<ErrorMessage ErrorMessage={()=>{getMessage()}} color={props.color} />
  or 
<ErrorMessage ErrorMessage={getMessage} color={props.color} />
or
<ErrorMessage ErrorMessage={getMessage()} color={props.color} />
```

and my getMessage function looks like below

```
 const getMessage = ()=> {
 console.log("get message:state"+state)
   if (state == 2) {
      // error
      return "Please enter valid user id";
   }
   if (state == 3) {
      // warning
      return "Please enter min 3 char";
   }  else {
      // success
     return "Valid user id";
   }
```

};

But in all cases app is throwing warning as *"React Native – Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it."** and app is not executing getMessage function body"*

**Please suggest how can we send prop to component using function return data.**

Comment: Only `<ErrorMessage ErrorMessage={getMessage()} color={props.color} />` will work for you. Because ErrorMessage is type string/int, but you are passing the function in first 2 cases.

Comment: Thanks it helped. I rename const as function and called as per ur comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the prop, and call it like

```
<ErrorMessage Message={getMessage()} color={props.color} />
```